# JSON to CSV/Excel in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, arraylist, json2csv

I am trying to convert the JSON:

Results:
console.log((`${JSON.stringify(results)}`);

```
[
[{"field":"StudentID","value":"A"},{"field":"Total Marks","value":"27853"}],[{"field":"StudentID","value":"B"},{"field":"Total Marks","value":"14337"}],[{"field":"StudentID","value":"C"},{"field":"Total Marks","value":"1324"}],[{"field":"StudentID","value":"D"},{"field":"Total Marks","value":"362"}],[{"field":"StudentID","value":"E"},{"field":"Total Marks","value":"209"}]]
```

to something a .csv file or excel file and download

```
Student ID  Total Marks
A           27853
B           14337
C           1324
D           362
E           209
```

Could someone provide a snippet of the js code that will help to implement this?

What I tried:

```
const json2csvParser = new Parser();
            results.forEach(element => {
                const csv = json2csvParser.parse(element);
                console.log(csv);
            });
            const csv = json2csvParser.parse(results);
            console.log(csv);
```

This just prints in the console as :

```
"field","value"
"Student ID","A"
"Total Marks","27853"
"field","value"
"Student ID","B"
"Total Marks","14337"
"field","value"
"Student ID","C"
"Total Marks","1324"
"field","value"
"Student ID","D"
"Total Marks","362"
"field","value"
"Student ID","E"
"Total Marks","209"
```

Comment: pretty sure this is a solved problem, what did you search for already?

Answer (score 0):

Download csv-parser npm pack.

```
npm i -s csv-parser
```

And for download;

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFileSync("demo.csv", csv);
console.log("Done!");
```

Basic tutorial for run at js page;

```
// (A) DATA ARRAY
var data = [
    ["Alpha", "Beta"],
    ["Charlie", "Delta"],
    ["Echo", "Foxtrot"]
  ];
  
  // (B) WRITE TO FILE
  const fs = require("fs");
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream("demoC.csv");
  for (let i of data) { stream.write(i.join(",") + "\r\n"); }
  stream.end();
  console.log("Done!");
```